# how to validate a required and numeric textbox using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I want to validate a textbox have numeric values using the following code, but i dont know the filter term there for numeric, my code is:

```
    function validateRequiredNumeric(Control, msgInfo) {
    var ControlId = $('#' + Control);
    var msgInfoId = $('#' + msgInfo);
    //testing regular expression
    var a = ControlId.val();
    var filter = /[^\d]/;
    alert(a.length);
    if (a.length != 0) {
        if (filter.test(a)) {
            msgInfoId.text('');
            ControlId.css({ 'border': '1px solid green' });
            return true;
        } else {
            //msgInfoId.css({ 'color': 'red', 'font-size': '12px', 'font-style': 'italic' });
            msgInfoId.text("Numeric Onlydd fdf dfd");
            ControlId.css({ 'border': '1px solid red' });
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        //msgInfoId.css({ 'color': 'red', 'font-size': '12px', 'font-style': 'italic' });
        msgInfoId.text("You can't leave this empty.");
        ControlId.css({ 'border': '1px solid red' });
        return false;
    }

}
```

Please help me.. i have tried the "**[^0-9]**" this also..

Comment: You only want to validate a textbox for having numeric values and should be a required field??

Comment: `/[^\d]/` matches all except digits it's a negated character class

Comment: @RatanSharma yes i want the same you explaining

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan ohhh ohk my mistake.. please help me what should i use there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regexp should be either:

For only numeric `/^[\d]+$/`

For any non-numeric `/^[^\d]+$/`

I am not sure what you mean in your question since your regexp try was for non-numeric.

Another answer made me think about it, if you expect users to use decimals, you should add some character cases...

For decimals `/^[\d]+[,.]?[\d]*$/`
requires at least one number before the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

try the [Texottela plugin](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/), enables using a `numeric()` function for that, and you can supply a callback that runs when focus is lost and the value in the text box is not a valid number.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the term you're looking for is a `regular expression`

This should do it:

```
var filter = /^\d*$/;
```

The carat `^` symbol will anchor the decimal to the start of the string
The `$` symbol anchors the decimal to the end of the string
and the `\d*` matches one or more decimal values

If there is any non-decimal in the string, the regex will return false

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex for that

```
    var a = Number($.trim(controlID));  //or parseInt($.trim(controlID))
    if (!isNaN(a)) {
        //a is valid number
    } else {
        //a is not a number or is empty
    }
```